# Firestore Update document in-place vs remove and insert

Tags: performance, google-cloud-firestore, query-performance

I’m trying to determine which of the following has the better performance for updating a document in Firestore/NoSQL in general.

Suppose that there is a sub-collection:

```
friends: 
- doc_id_sjfn
      • last_name=Wang
      • last_talked=10sec ago
      • actual_user_id=wang1997
- doc_id_wokm
      • last=Liu
      • last_talked=12min ago
      • actual_user_id=liu98
```

and the client attaches a listener to the sub-collection and displays the sub-collection in real-time on a list view.

Suppose that we want to change Wang’s last_talked to 15 sec ago with app engine over google cloud.

When updating the list, is the performance better when

A: delete document doc_id_sjfn and insert document with doc_id_sjfn_v2 as ID

B: update field ‘last_talked’ of document doc_id_sjfn to 15 seconds ago

Since there are warnings against updating a document in-place for more than once per second, would approach A have better performance in terms of how long it takes for the change to be reflected on the list displayed on the client device? Under what condition is this faster? (If fields are indexed vs not indexed) (if the list view contains every element under the collection vs a subset of all elements under the collection using “where”)

Thanks!

(The example was edited; there are definitely better ways of implementing this use case, but the example is here to help me express the idea of using document as a view and needing constant refresh)

Answer (score 0):

The rule of once per second is for specific documents. From the looks of the data it doesn't look like data that will update more than once per... year?

I wouldn't worry about the once per second with the data set presented and just update in place. You'll introduce a headache trying to reconcile old and new documents, e.g. you have v1, how do you know there isn't a v2?

Comment: What if the data is updated at multiple times per second? The example was used mostly to introduce the idea of using a document as a view of data from other documents.